# Models in LOOPBACK

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I create my first loopback project and model name I gave it as **notes** after starting the project I found in the localhost a model named **user** been created (but I didn't create it) and also found **login** and **logout** methods but don't know how it's working, when I tried it said "authorization required" since I'm new to LOOPBACK I need your help.

```
{
"error": {
   "message" : "authorization required"
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you created a Loopback project with authentication. In this case, kind Loopback creates a auth structure for you, that by default search for a 'user' table. Also you need an related table for the accessToken. Since you aren't sending the auth token, then its response is 401 (authorization required).

See https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Introduction+to+User+model+authentication for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much @Luiz Fernando da Silva because of your link i found a solution for my problem ...